# Howto make holes in cubes with openscad / for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, rotation, cube, openscad

I want to make a hole in each of these cubes.
Here is the code:

```
y=45;
for (i=[1:8]){
    z = y*i;
    difference(){
        rotate([0,0,z]) translate([57,0,-5]) cube(center = true,[5,10,10]);
        rotate([90,90,z]) translate([6,0,-60]) cylinder(5,2,2);  
    }
    
}
// This is a reference, translate([6,0,-60]) is correct position
rotate([90,90,z]) translate([16,0,-60]) cylinder(5,2,2);
```

Why

```
rotate([90,90,z]) translate([6,0,-60]) cylinder(5,2,2);
```

do not work in a for loop?
When `z` is setting manually to 45, 90, 135, 180...315 the holes are correct.

Comment: Coordinates are way off for the cylinder due to the different rotations. Things are easier when combining the parts first in a convenient location around the origin and moving into place last, like

    rotate([0,0,z]) translate([57,0,-5]) difference() {
            cube(center = true,[5,10,10]);
            rotate([0,90,0]) cylinder(6,2,2,center=true);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

So the main loop will position your cuboids rotated around the origin
at an angle which is a multiple of 45 degrees.  Inside the loop, you
now want to draw the cuboids, and right after that, relative to the
position of each cuboid, you make a few more transformations (a rotation
and translation) to get the cylinders to pass through the centers of the
cuboids (It also helps if the height of the cylinder is bigger than the
side of the cuboid so you can actually see it passing through):

```
y=45;
for (i=[1:8]){
    z = y*i;    
    rotate([0,0,z]) translate([57,0,-5])
    {
        cube(center=true,[5,10,10]);
        rotate([0,90,0]) translate([0,0,-5]) cylinder(r=2,h=10,$fn=100);
    };
}
```

[image]

Now that you know the positions are correct, you can apply the boolean difference and obtain the hole at the center of each cuboid:

```
y=45;
for (i=[1:8]){
    z = y*i;    
    rotate([0,0,z]) translate([57,0,-5])
    difference() {
        cube(center=true,[5,10,10]);
        rotate([0,90,0]) translate([0,0,-5]) cylinder(r=2,h=10,$fn=100) ;
    }
}
```

[image]

You can find all the [code for this here](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/tree/master/so-65445132).